# Usage and meaning of “auf” + Akk. + “schauen”

Tags: meaning

*Schauen* can be combined with a number of prepositions.

> Ich schaue zu/unter/hinter/aus/in...

For most of them, the local implication is pretty clear, however not for *auf:*

> 1. Ich ***schaue auf*** das Haus von gegenüber.

That doesn’t mean that I am looking at it from above.

- When is *auf etwas schauen* used and what does it mean?

Comment: "Ihr Völker der Welt, schaut auf diese Stadt!"

Comment: Für mich impliziert das gefühlsmäßig "von oben", wenn es nicht metaphorisch gemeint ist, was wohl der üblichere Anwendungsfall ist. Deinen Satz könntest du z.B. sagen, wenn du mit dem Ballon über deines Nachbarn Haus fährst. Dann paßt aber "gegenüber" wieder nicht richtig.

Comment: @Info Könnte ja vom Blickpunkt eines höheren Gebäudes sein. Insofern würde es auch mit *gegenüber* passen.

Comment: In Southern Germany, Austria and Switzerland "schauen auf" also means: "sich kümmern um jemanden" (to look after somebody). "Ich schaue auf das Kind meiner Schwester."

Comment: Hö? Hab ich was verpasst "Ich schaue auf das Haus von gegenüber" == "Ich schaue auf das gegenüberliegende Haus". Ich stehe hier auf dem Boden, vor meinem eigenen Haus und schaue auf das sich auf der andere Straßenseite gelegende Haus. Ich muss nicht oben sein. Ich kann mich sogar unterhalb befinden.

Comment: @Em1 ist ja recht. Ich würde in dem Fall trotzdem "Ich schaue das gegenüberliegende Haus an." sagen.

Comment: @Ingo Interessanterweise würde ich dann sagen "Ich schaue mir das gegenüberliegende Haus an." Ein nicht-refelxives *anschauen* käme mir nicht in den Sinn.

Comment: @splattne Stimmt, und auch im Sinne von "darauf achten, dafür sorgen": *Sie schaut darauf, immer modisches Schuhwerk zu tragen."

Comment: @Em1 Es liegt am Beispiel. Genaugenommen schaut man das gegenüberliegende Haus eben nicht an, und man schaut es **sich** allenfalls an, wenn es einem zum Kauf angeboten wird. Den Rest der Zeit schaut man ab und zu aus dem Fenster, und das gegenüberliegende Haus befindet sich dann im Sichtfeld. :) Ich finde die nicht wörtlichen Bedeutungen von "schauen ... auf" wesentlich spannender.

Comment: Do you also `wait from above` when you say `Ich warte auf etwas`? `Schauen auf` means simply `to look at`. Your sentence means `I am looking at the house in front of me`. By the way in Polish it is `patrzyć na` which is exactly a literal translation of `schauen auf`. Pretty nice, isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's try to collect some of the meanings, many of which are figurative. (I don't mind to add anything, please let me know through comments.)

> Aus dem Küchenfenster schaut man direkt auf die Kirche.  *From the kitchen, one can see the church.*

As has been pointed out, this does not necessarily imply that one sees the church from above. Nevertheless, this meaning is indeed possible:

> Ich schaue beschämt auf einen Punkt am Boden. *I look ashamed at a point on the ground.*

In the sense "to read off some information"

> Ich schaue/blicke auf die Uhr, die Anzeige, das Tachometer.

In the southern dialects, we have the figurative meaning "to care about someone/something":

> Ich schaue auf das Kind meiner Schwester. *I look after my sister's child.*

And also figuratively "pay attention":

> Ich schaue auf saubere Kleidung. *I pay attention to clean clothes.*

Note that in standard German one would say:

> Ich achte auf saubere Kleidung. Ich passe auf das Kind meiner Schwester auf.

Also:

> Wenn ich auf die Vergangenheit schaue, ... *When I look at the past, ...*
>
> Er schaut mit Verachtung auf seine Angestellten. *He looks at his employees with contempt.*
>
> zu jemandem aufschauen *to admire someone, to look up to someone*
>
> auf jemanden herabschauen *to despise, to look down on someone*

Answer (score 0):

With *auf* it simply specifies the surface/object you are referring to or looking at, while *von oben* definetly means *from above*:

> Ich schaue von oben *auf* das Haus.